# Change database connect on production server

Tags: php, fuelphp

where can I change the database connection on my production server?
I changed it here fuel/app/config/production/db.php. But how does fuelphp know which settings it should use?

I'm using nginx as webserver on Ubuntu.

The error message is:

```
1045!

Fuel\Core\Database_Exception [ 1045 ]:
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user '**********'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the bootstrap file (fuel/app/bootstrap.php):

```
Fuel::$env = (isset($_SERVER['FUEL_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['FUEL_ENV'] : Fuel::DEVELOPMENT);
```

You can create a server variable with the name "FUEL_ENV" and the value "production". 
Put something like this in your nginx vhost file:

```
location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param FUEL_ENV production; # this one
}
```